# Python encoding problems

Tags: python, django, encoding, twitter, utf-8

So, I've read a lot about Python encoding and stuff - maybe not enough but I've been working on this for 2 days and still nothing - but I'm still getting troubles. I'll try to be as clear as I can. The main thing is that I'm trying to remove all accents and characters such as #, !, %, &...

The thing is, I do a query search on Twitter Search API with this call:

```
query = urllib2.urlopen(settings.SEARCH_URL + '?%s' % params)
```

Then, I call a method (`avaliar_pesquisa()`) to evaluate the results I've got, based on the tags (or terms) of the input:

```
dados = avaliar_pesquisa(simplejson.loads(query.read()), str(tags))
```

On `avaliar_pesquisa()`, the following happens:

```
def avaliar_pesquisa(dados, tags):
    resultados = []
    # Percorre os resultados
    for i in dados['results']
        resultados.append({'texto'          : i['text'],
                           'imagem'         : i['profile_image_url'],
                           'classificacao'  : avaliar_texto(i['text'], tags),
                           'timestamp'      : i['created_at'],
                         })
```

Note the `avaliar_texto()` which evaluates the Tweet text. And there's exactly the problem on the following lines:

```
def avaliar_texto(texto, tags):
    # Remove accents
    from unicodedata import normalize
    def strip_accents(txt):
        return normalize('NFKD', txt.decode('utf-8'))

    # Split
    texto_split = strip_accents(texto)
    texto_split = texto.lower().split()

    # Remove non-alpha characters
    import re
    pattern = re.compile('[\W_]+')
    texto_aux = []
    for i in texto_split:
        texto_aux.append(pattern.sub('', i))
    texto_split = texto_aux
```

The split doesn't really matter here.
The thing is, if I print the type of the var `texto` on this last method, I may get str or unicode as answer. If there is any kind of accent on the text, it comes like unicode.
So, I get this error running the application that receives 100 tweets max as answer:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in
>   position 17: ordinal not in range(128)

For the following text:

> Text: Agora o problema é com o speedy. 
>   type 'unicode'

Any ideas?

Comment: Which is the exact line that triggers that error message? Do you have a backtrace?

Comment: Which line of your code does the UnicodeEncodeError occur on?

Comment: @Jong The exact line is on the normalize function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I used in my code to discard accents, etc.

```
text = unicodedata.normalize('NFD', text).encode('ascii','ignore')
```

Comment: For this, I get: TypeError: must be unicode, not str. So, as suggested below, I added the `unicode(text)` cast inside de `normalize()`function. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 9):

See [this page](http://wiki.python.org/moin/UnicodeEncodeError).

The `decode()` method is to be applied to a str object, not a unicode object. Given a unicode string as input, it first tries to encode it to a str using the ascii codec, then decode as utf-8, which fails.

Try `return normalize('NFKD', unicode(txt) )`.

Comment: Mixed your solution to the one accepted above. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Ty placing:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

at the beginning of your python script containing the code.

Comment: I think that only affects the interpretation of the program text itself, not any data from an outside source.

Comment: From what I could figure out, if you place that at the beginning, your python code will be interpreted as utf8, meaning all strings too. I had a similar problem with romanian characters and I got it fixed by placing that on top.